# Unable to change two things about a single row in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the code:

```
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
$score = "'" . $_POST['score'] . "'";
$shares = "'" . $_POST['shares'] . "'";

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=news', 'root', '');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE news SET 'shares' = :shares, 'score' = :score 
WHERE id = :id");
$stmt -> execute(array(
    'shares' => $shares,
    'score' => $score,
    'id' => $id
    ));
```

And it doesn't work. I am unsure as to how I would see the error that I assume mysql is giving somewhere, and I've tried everything I could think of.

Using double quotes and adding the variables into the statement right away.

Adding single quotes to shares and score.

How am I supposed to be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the quote from the column names e.g. below:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE news SET shares = :shares, score = :score 
                                                                  WHERE id = :id");
```

Also better to use `bindParam` method to bind the parameters.

```
$stmt ->bindParam(':shares', $shares, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt ->bindParam(':score', $score, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt ->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt -> execute();
```

I am assuming all the fields are INT type. If not, please update with the appropriate type.

Comment: I don't know how to get the message. I'm using phpmyadmin.

Comment: @user1624005: Can you please try the update answer and let me know?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have forgotten the colon in execute statement, here goes the edited code.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE news SET shares = :shares, score = :score 
WHERE id = :id");
$stmt -> execute(array(
    ':shares' => $shares,
    ':score' => $score,
    ':id' => $id
    ));
```